# The MDX function CURRENTMEMBER failed because the coordinate for the 'Date' attribute contains a set

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to run this query:

```
select [Dim Date].[Date] on ROWS,
{[Measures].[Available Time Net],[Measures].[Logged On Time Net]} on columns 
from [OTS Agent Time Net Data]
where {[Dim Date].[Date].&[08/01/2014]:[Dim Date].[Date].&[12/31/2014]}
```

I want to get the measures that exist in the `where` clause, but I also want to show the dates on the rows. I keep getting an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just add the set directly to the `ROWS` ?

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Dim Date].[Date].&[08/01/2014] : [Dim Date].[Date].&[12/31/2014]
    } ON ROWS
 ,{
    [Measures].[Available Time Net]
   ,[Measures].[Logged On Time Net]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [OTS Agent Time Net Data];
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the same hierarchy ([Dim Date].[Date]) both on one axis and in the slicer ([MDX tutorial](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html)); I guess using a sub-query would be fine for your example:

```
select 
  [Dim Date].[Date] on ROWS,
  {[Measures].[Available Time Net],[Measures].[Logged On Time Net]} on columns 

from ( 
  select {[Dim Date].[Date].&[08/01/2014]:[Dim Date].[Date].&[12/31/2014]} on 0 
  from [OTS Agent Time Net Data] 
)
```

Hope that helps.

(edit: using a named-set or using the slicer content right in the axis - see other responses - is a bit different because the request is filtering on a range of days but select [Dim Date].[Date] does not necessarily displays days; that could for example be the 'All' of the hierarchy of [Dim Date].[Date])

Comment: @Basil - You would probably need to replace `[Dim Date].[Date] on ROWS,` with `[Dim Date].[Date].MEMBERS on ROWS,` to get the dates on the row axis. Otherwise, you would just be seeing the `All` member there.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti - if that is the name of a level then `.MEMBERS` is not required.

Comment: @whytheq - Hey there! Long time. Sorry, I did not get that.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti hi - hope you are well. All I'm saying is `SELECT {} ON 0, [Date].[Date].[Date] ON 1 FROM [Adventure Works]`

Comment: Marc, neither of the other answers use [Din Date]. [Date] alone. Please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marc's answer and that's probably the best way to do it. But there is one more way to do it, which doesn't need subselect, by making use of named sets.

```
with set DateRange AS
{[Dim Date].[Date].&[08/01/2014]:[Dim Date].[Date].&[12/31/2014]}

select NON EMPTY  DateRange on ROWS,
{[Measures].[Available Time Net],[Measures].[Logged On Time Net]} on COLUMNS 
from [OTS Agent Time Net Data]
```

**EDIT**

As per your request, if you want to additionally filter by time, here's one way to proceed. Replace the defenition of set `DateRange` with the below:

```
with set DateRange AS
EXISTS({[Dim Date].[Date].&[08/01/2014]:[Dim Date].[Date].&[12/31/2014]}
       ,[Dim Time].[Time].&[1930]
       , "Time Net"
      )
```

Few things which you need to fill in here..

Assuming time dimension's hierarchy to be `[Dim Time].[Time]`. Please replace with the actual name along with the member's format(Assumed it to be `&[1930]`

Also, `Time Net` is the measure group name to which the measures `[Measures].[Available Time Net]` and `[Measures].[Logged On Time Net]` belong to. Again, replace with original name.

Comment: ,I'm wondering, if i now wanted to add a time dimension: since i have my date range, could i add an additional range ? or should i cross join ?

Comment: Same hierarchy or different hierarchy? How?

Comment: No, it's a different dimension and hierarchy. I meant a different names set, the. Query back to have both time and date dimensions

Comment: Umm. If you just want to filter by time dimension, crossjoin is not required. You could just use EXISTS clause then. But if you want to display that, you could create tuples out of time and date dimension or crossjoin.

Comment: I actually want to show the results of every call offered at the 19:30 between the dates of 10/13/2013 and 01/13/2014

Comment: So, a filter then. I will edit my answer for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Appreciate that

Comment: Ok. Does that get me one value for 19:30 for the date range selected? I apologize in very Green to mdx, it's got a heck of a learnt mg curve compared to Sql

Comment: So what it does is that it gets you the values of the measures for all the given dates in the date range **AND** at 19:30.

Comment: You got a chance to test it out?

Comment: i did, i tried it like this with a different cube, same date and time dimensions:

Comment: with set DateRange AS
EXISTS({[Dim Date].[Date].&[08/01/2014]:[Dim Date].[Date].&[12/31/2014]}
       ,[Dim Time].[Hour-Half Hour Hierarchy].[Half Hour of Day].&[17:30]
      
      )


select NON EMPTY  DateRange on ROWS,
{[Measures].[Network Calls Received]} on COLUMNS 
from [OTS Analysis Services]

Comment: The problem with the above query, is that it doesn't display the time, only the date, and i still have the problem, where it's displaying data outside of the range: 10/13/13 - 01/13/14, it's dispalying data from year 2015 and2013 before 10/13/13

Comment: Well it is counter productive to display time when you have only one value of it, isn't it? That being said, it's easily fixable. And I believe you have another open question on the other concern. Let me tell you all the answers given here would generally work with each having something better about them. Why you are getting data out of range is a separate I issue altogether and certainly an unrelated topic.

Comment: well, can i open another topic for the out of range? and you can help me with that? that is the main issue i'm having. I can get just the dates, but i need to find out the data in that date range, that happend at the 7PM hour..... so all network calls received at 7 pm, between the dates of 10/13/2013 and 01/13/2014.....i only need one row to return.